# Subversion ignore local changes to single file on merge

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to ignore changes to a single local file when merging another branch?

What I have is a batch file that makes changes to a single file and then launches the commit dialog in TortoiseSVN. This results in a conflict with that file on every merge but in every case, I want the server version of that one file while not interfering with the normal conflict process of all other files.

I have not found anything promising in any google search or the docs as far as I have looked. I likely am not searching for the correct terms or just doing something that is a very uncommon practice.

The requirement for the project that I am working on is to have the revision number of current working copy checked out to be displayed in the footer. The easiest way I have found to do this is to use a file `version.txt` that has the keywords to be replaced. We commit using a batch file that just updates this file then launches the TortoiseSVN dialog so we can commit like before with the GUI. The local working copies and the development server work like this. Production uses a deployment script that cleans things up a bit so we can just export the specific tagged release.

Comment: Are you sure you want the file in question in the repository at all? If not, you could delete it from the repository (saving a copy) and add it to the ignore list in the Commit or Check for modifications dialogue.

Comment: Maybe not but that seems to be the only way to have it modify keywords on commit

Comment: “modify keywords” — there seems to be a requirement here you might tell us more about! Maybe someone can come up with a cleaner solution if we know more exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: And is your problem then that when you merge one branch to another, both have copies of  `version.txt` which have been differently updated and therefore conflict, while you do not really care about the changes, as all you want is the value of the (`$Revision$`?) keyword?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have established that your functional requirement is to incorporate the current revision of your Working Copy into any build done there (in the footer of some document).

#### Your current approach

You have a file, `version.txt`, containing the `$Revision$` keyword, which (if enabled) Subversion, replaces as described in the manual under [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)<sup>1</sup> *(my emphasis)*:

> This … describes the … revision in which **this file** changed …, and looks … like $Revision: 144 $.

You update `version.txt` (somehow or other) with a script before each commit, to ensure that the last revision of this file is that of the branch on which the Working Copy is based. The process deriving the revision number from `version.txt` is presumably insensitive to the arbitrary changes you use to ensure the latest revision.

#### Your problem

The disadvantage you have observed is that when you merge from one branch to another, the arbitrary changes made to `version.txt` in both branches mean that `version.txt` is always conflicted. After such a merge you therefore need first to resolve the conflict (your commit-script will as usual automatically apply a new arbitrary change).

You have therefore asked for a way to ignore your local changes and automatically use the `version.txt` in the repository from which you are merging.

#### The suggested Subversion approach

Your arbitrary change to `version.txt` is your solution the problem described in a box under “Where’s `$GlobalRev$`?” on [the same page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html)<sup>1</sup> of the manual:

> New users are often confused by … $Rev$ … Since the repository has a global… revision number…, many people assume that … this … is reflected by … $Rev$ …. … frustration often remains — without … a … keyword …, how can you … get the global revision number …?
>
> … Subversion ships with a tool called svnversion … for … this purpose. It crawls your working copy and generates as output the revision(s) it finds. You can use this … to embed that revision … into your files. For more information …, see [svnversion Reference](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.html)<sup>1</sup>.

The output from `svnversion` shows you the range of revisions in your working copy and whether it is mixed, modified and/or sparse, ee.g. `4168` or `4123:4168MSP`.

#### Other approaches and observations

- You can continue with your current approach, and, when you merge, resolve the conflicts automatically with `svn`[`resolve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html)<sup>1</sup>`--accept theirs-full`*`<WC-path>`*.

  - You may find it more convenient to merge `version.txt` first, with `svn merge`[`--accept theirs-full`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.accept)<sup>1</sup>*`<Source-URL>/version.txt <WC-path>/version.txt`*.
  - Whether you use `mine-full` `theirs-full` or anything else does not really matter, given that you only extract the revision number and ignore the arbitrary changes (as long as that process still works).
- You can convert the output from `svn`[`info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html)<sup>1</sup>*`<WC-path>`*. I mention this as it is the approach I have used in the past, but you would probably find `svnversion` more appropriate.
- When you build a tag, your problem does not normally arise: creating and checking out a tag will yield a `version.txt` with the revision number of the tag.
- If you build on multiple platforms, some of which have no `svn info`/`svnversion`, so that you copy to them with e.g. `ftp`, you may • generate the `svn*`-output before copying, • use the `$Revision$` keyword, or • leave out the revision on that platform.

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Note that references are to version 1.8 of the manual, which was still current as of 2018-12-27; if in doubt, check http://www.svnbook.com/.</sub>

**Edits**

*2015-06-16 Dealing with non-`svn` platforms*

*2018-12-27 State version of manual referenced*

Comment: Going to give this a try but it seems our IT left out the command line tools when installing TortoiseSVN so I must wait (hopefully only a few days).

Comment: How short-sighted of them! Good luck once you get that far!

Comment: When you install TortoiseSVN, you have the option to also install the command line client. If you're technical enough to use Subversion, you're technical enough to handle the command line client too. The CLI can help you diagnose issues that you may see in the GUI. Let your Tech team know. Request that they *update* your TortoiseSVN client and install the optional CLI when they do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your use case is. Files that are user/computer specific should not be part of your SVN repository. Perhaps you can try to parameterize your batch file?

With respect to merging: in principle, one should always merge in a *clean* working directory.

If you really must continue your current way of working, you can fix your working directory after the merge from the command line with `svn resolve` (see `svn help resolve`):

```
svn resolve --accept theirs-full <your file>
```

Answer (score 1):

> batch file that makes changes to a single file and then launches the commit dialog in TortoiseSVN

**Bad Idea (tm)** in common. Bat-file can also silently commit using CLI of SVN

> I want the server version of that one file

Bad unclean term. **All** commited files in all nodes (branches) are "server version". You have to write "my" or "another" version of changed file have to be stored in "my" of "another" branch after merge in order to get full answer.

Short draft answer *now* will be:

- Merge single (your changed) file with another branch's file before merging full tree, using `--accept` option with needed ARG for requested result
- Merge full branch